# How to use MySQL's MATCH AGAINST in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, mysql

I am trying to search a custom post type using a `WP_Query` like the following:

```
$searchTerm = '%my book%';
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'books',
    'meta_query' = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'book_title',
            'value' => $searchTerm,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'book_description',
            'value' => $searchTerm,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The query above works just fine. In fact I can change the `compare` operator for any of the mysql supported operators like:

```
=,
\>=,
<=,
\>,
<,
LIKE,
RLIKE,
BETWEEN
```

However I am not able to figure out how to use the operator `MATCH AGAINST`. In MySQL it works like this:

```
select *
from wp_postmeta
where meta_key = 'book_title'
and match(meta_value) against ('my book');
```

But I can't figure out a way to use it with `WP_Query`, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a fulltext index on the meta value column for that type of raw SQL query to work. Wouldn't there be many unrelated values/rows added to the index, that are not for book titles?

Comment: That was just a sample query in reality I will be querying more than just book_title. But even then yes, there will be indexes for rows that don't need it. However, the benefits this index will provide overcome the disadvantages for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't use `MATCH()... AGAINST` in `WP_Query`. The possible values for comparison are the following:

```
=
!=
>
>=
<
<= 
LIKE
NOT LIKE
IN
NOT IN
BETWEEN
NOT BETWEEN
NOT EXISTS
REGEXP
NOT REGEXP
RLIKE
```

Which the default is `=`. However, you can use `MATCH() AGAINST` in a generic query to use by `$wpdb`. For example:

```
$wpdb->prepare(" AND MATCH($wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->posts.post_content) AGAINST(%s)", $search );
```

There are also some `__not_in` parameters you can use in your query, such as:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) );
```

Which will search the posts that don't have the tag IDs of 1, 2 and 3.

This [Codex Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [Core ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14722) might be able to help you.